Push notifications not recieving in android in hybrid app
We are developing an hybrid app in ionic and we want to implement push notifications feature using this plugin(https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin).We have followed all the steps in readme and capacitor implementation guide(https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin/blob/master/capacitor_doc.md), in IOS it's working fine but in android,we have followed all the steps for implementation but we aren't recieving the push notifications in our devices although the notifications are shown as delivered in marketing cloud.What can be the problem?isn't compulsory to use the sender id in code or in the dashboard?(We have already the sender_id added to firebase)Thanks for your help.

Please open a support case

How can i open it?

Contact you Account Executive.
